# Creating array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 19.04 and bash 4.4.20

I'm trying to create a shell script to add two elements to an array but seem to be only creating a string containing the first element.

I expect to have an array with 2 elements in but the output only has the first element

```
ARRAY=("element1" "element2")

echo $ARRAY # output => element1

echo $ARRAY[0] # output => element1[0]
```

Comment: Use `${ARRAY[0]}`. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays), "Any element of an array may be referenced using...". `$ARRAY` is a shorthand for `${ARRAY[0]}`.

Comment: yep, that solved it thanks

Answer (score 0):

The out you see should have given you the hint. Your syntax for accessing a bash array is incorrect. According to the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays), the correct syntax is:

```
${ARRAY[index]}
```

So, you should be using:

```
${ARRAY[*]} # output => element1 element2
${ARRAY[0]} # output => element1
```

I'd recommend you to read the bash manual for these things. There's also `${ARRAY[@]}`, but I leave its interpretation as an exercise to the reader.